# capture jquery keypress input and log to console

Tags: jquery, keypress

My simple jQuery keypress script is not working.
All i want to do is capture the input on a textarea (id = story) and log the key that was pressed to the console. I want the character logged to the console to be the actual character that was pressed as opposed to the keycode. I had some confusion between keyup and keypress events, but i have tried both, and i constructed the code below based on the jQuery documentation.

```
<script>
$('#story').keypress(function()
{


    var txtInput = this.value;


    console.log(txtInput);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#story').keyup(function()
    {   

        var txtInput = $(this).val();
        txtInput = txtInput.charAt(txtInput.length-1);
        alert(txtInput);

    });
});
```

Comment: That was something i tried on a previous iteration, but just tried it again and no luck? I dont get anything logged in the console. It seems as if the event never fires?

Comment: Ive updated mine a little bit and you can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/Rrxha/1/ where you running it on document ready ?

Comment: that did the trick thank you. I noticed you changed over to keyup, so i've done the same thing. I wasnt running it on document.ready. I totally forget the dom needs to be initialised before we can start using it.

Comment: cool glad it worked i changed to key up because on key down you would get the last key you pressed down as the key has not technicaly been added to the input field. Good luck with the rest off your project